# PHP static class variables still holding values after initial instantiation

Tags: php, oop

I have:

```
class A {
    static $instances = 0;
    public $instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$instances;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new A();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
echo "</pre>";
```

Outputs:

```
A Object
(
    [instance] => 1
)
A Object
(
    [instance] => 2
)
```

I know that static variables still retain their values after exiting functions but this is in a class context. How come in this class context the class still retains the variable when a new instance is created.

Any references to official documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables are not associated to any particular instance/object of a class. 
 The same is for the static variable inside of the class's method ... (comments in http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> So if you declare a variable as static inside a function, it's static
>   for the whole class and all of its instances, not for each object.

and

> The difference between static and non static members is only that a
>   non static member is tied to an instance of a class although a static
>   member is tied to the class, and not to a particular instance. That
>   is, a static member is shared by all instances of a class although a
>   non static member exists for each instance of  class.

Comment: Thanks! The PHP documentation is horrible.

Comment: What about a __destruct() to unset or reset the variables? I haven't tried that personally with a static object, but sounds like it might work for ya.

Comment: @sonic720 __destruct() is related to the instance of the class (works with objects), not to the class in general

Answer (score 1):

I had to read this from the Java documentation to understand why:

> When a number of objects are created from the same class blueprint,
>   they each have their own distinct copies of instance variables.
>
> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
>   This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
>   static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
>   variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any
>   object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
>   in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
>   class variable...

Answer (score 0):

The new instantiation doesn't retain the static variable, rather you're incrementing the class's $instances then saving the result into the instantiation's $instance.